# Check whether the method is returning a value or null and based on that assign the value

Tags: c#, null

I have a scenario where I am assigning value to a class property in the below way.

```
var appResponse = GetAppResponse();
appResponse.LogoImage = GetAppImage(appId);
```

The problem here is sometimes GetImage(appId) returns null and in that case I don’t want to assign that null value to appResponse.LogoImage, only when GetImage(appId) returns a value then only I want to assign that value.

I can use an If condition to check if GetImage(appId) is returning null or not and then assign the value, but then I will be making 2 calls to the method GetImage() which is not a good approach I feel.

In a single line can I check for null and when it is not null then only assign value to appResponse.LogoImage?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would do if the value is null? I'm not seeing why an `if(appResponse.LogoImage != null)` statement is a bad approach if you have two paths to accommodate two different actions

Comment: It doesn't have to be 2 calls to GetImage, you can store the result of the call in a variable and then check if the variable is null. what's the value of LogoImage supposed to be if it is null? You can try use the null coalescing operator if it must be one line.

Comment: Just go with the `if` - there's no need for anything fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can use a If condition to check if GetImage(appId) is returning null
> or not and then assign the value, but then I will be making 2 calls to
> the method GetImage()

Why would you be calling it twice?

Here's just one call:

```
var appResponse = GetAppResponse();
var appImage = GetAppImage(appId);
if (appImage != null) {
    appResponse.LogoImage = appImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator): `??`

```
appResponse.LogoImage = GetAppImage(appId) ?? appResponse.LogoImage;
```

From the docs:

> The null-coalescing operator `??` returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. The `??` operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.